# Ajax within editor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm fairly new to MVVM / MVC with Asp.net Core 2.  So please forgive me if this is an easy question.  Ha.

I have an editor template within a view.  Basically a form within a form.  When submitted using the button within the Editor template, I want to update JUST that template using AJAX.  I cannot seem to get it to work.  Is it possible?

```
<form asp-action="edit">

        //FORM FIELDS REMOVED FOR BREVITY

        <div class="hide" id="selectListItems">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ovm.opt, "CreateCtrlOption")
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Editor Template:

```
 <form asp-controller="ctrls" asp-action="CreateCtrlOption" data-ajax="true" 
data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="onSuccess" data-ajax-update="divOpts">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="CtrlId" id="CtrlId" value="@ViewBag.ctrlId" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Value" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Value" class="form-control" name="Value" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Value" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Other than the `onSuccess` method, do I need any other javascript for this to work?

I do have ajax unobtrusive referenced.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nested forms are invalid html and not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, as Stephen pointed out, I removed the nested form references.  I also specified a URL action specifically for the submit button within the editor template.

Like so

`<input type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("CreateCtrlOption")" id="ctrlOptionSubmit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />`